# Do I need to salt PBKDF2 when it's used for AES encryption

Tags: passwords, aes, salt, pbkdf2

If I'm using PBKDF2 to stretch a password into a suitable key for use in encryption with AES, should I be using a random salt (for PBKDF2, not the AES IV)?

Comment: You can leave out the AES IV if you use a per-message salt. But you should not leave out the salt even when you use an IV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Absolutely!** It's even right there in the [PKCS #5 v2.0](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-5v2/pkcs5v2-0.pdf)

> A salt in password-based cryptography has traditionally served the
>   purpose of producing a large set of keys corresponding to a given
>   password, among which one is selected at random according to the salt.

By using a secure salt, password `p1 = tomato` will not produce the same key as `p2 = tomato` even though they're the same password. This has two benefits:

- Protection against rainbow tables.
- Only one password can be attacked at a time. The same computational effort can't be utilized to "reverse" more than one password.

Answer (score 1):

**You must do this**, as otherwise two users using the same password twice will generate the same key.  The effort of using a salt is almost none, yet increases your security.

**Please refrain from rolling your own there is a standard and you should use it!**

It's healthy to question the "whys" from a learning perspective but playing with crypto and trying to cut corners can be dangerous if you are not an experienced cryptographer.